# Graphics card Quadro P4000 display issue

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, display

Graphics card Quadro P4000 is not working properly in my work station in #Ubuntu v18.4 server. Display problem occurs every time.
I have tried to update drivers also but, it's not working. It shows a black screen only after the restart. Please provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: What is your driver version? Are you using the proprietary or the open source driver?

Comment: Open source driver

Comment: I have P6000 but with the proprietary driver.

Comment: I have tried proprietary driver also. But, couldn't work. Can you please provide ma steps to install  proprietary driver.?

Comment: Sure, first install the graphics PPA: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, then open the `Additional Drivers` dialog and select the desired Driver, if you don't have a display at all (`nomodeset` doesn't work, etc.) you can try and install the drivers directly from Nvidia: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us, it may cause a lot of problems on your side so use it only if nothing else worked.